# Breaking of nuclei having small binding energy

Tags: nuclear-physics

I calculated the binding energy for the helium nucleus and it came out to be 4.533* 10^-12 J.Which is a very,very small amount. So why can't we break the Nuclei having similar small binding energy as that of Helium just by simple heating ? For instance why can't we break the Helium Nuclei like that ? . Knowing that it has such small Binding Energy.

Comment: How are you concentrating all of that heat energy on a single helium nucleus?

Answer (score 1):

I have not checked if the binding energy you calculated is correct, but let's suppose it is. We know that thermal energy scales as $k_B T$ where $k_B$ is the Boltzmann constant:
\begin{equation}
k_B T \sim 4.5\times10^{-12}\,\mathrm{J} \iff T \sim 3 \times 10^{11}\,\mathrm{K}
\end{equation}
Sure, this is a rough order-of-magnitude estimation, but calculations like this are very important to get a feeling for scale. It is not so easy to achieve temperatures like that.

EDIT: This is by the way close to the order of magnitude for the temperature in the early universe at which primordial nucleosynthesis started ($10^{10} - 10^{9}\,\mathrm{K}$). Before that, the temperature/thermal energy was too high for Helium etc. to form.